# Permanently change Squid access.log permissions

Tags: linux, logrotate, squid

I have a `squid` user, writing to `access.log` with `640` permissions.

Also an `nrpe` user, reading `access.log`, but only works with `644` permissions.

```
chmod 644 access.log
```

Does the trick, but only until the next reboot. Curiously, `logrotate` preserves the set permissions happily.

I would like that to be persistent across reboots.

I've looked at `squid.conf` - there doesn't seem to be anything helpful within the log settings.

I can't set the squid user `umask` (nologon)
I added `'$FileCreateMode 0666'` to `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

But this doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much like Maat's answer I went with adding squid group to nrpe since that is the default configuration & squid group already having read access.

```
usermod -aG squid nrpe
systemctl restart nrpe
```

The restart forces `nrpe` to relog which forces the group update.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use unix group with `nrpe` user as member.

```
groupadd squidaccess
usermod -aG squidaccess nrpe
```

That group must be proprietary of access.log file.

```
chown :squidaccess access.log
```

Using that kind of configuration will match 640 permissions

I prefer that kind of permissions which is most secure than a 644 which give any account the right to read the file.

Comment: Brilliant. I don't know how I've overlooked that.